# Cómo consumir un servicio externo por https desde wso2 esb

Tags: wso2

Estoy haciendo un servicio en wso2 esb que consuma otro servicio externo por https para ello tuve que enviar por el encabezado el tocken de autorizacion.
Este es mi codigo:

```
        <property action="remove" name="Accept" scope="transport"/>
        <header name="accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
        <header name="To" scope="default" value="Authorization:Bearer f5e6aeb4-0be0-3542-b790-e8ce07dd17ab"/>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:new="http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                    <soap:Header/>
                    <soap:Body>
                        <new:select_promotor_id_query>
                            <id_promotor>$1</id_promotor>
                        </new:select_promotor_id_query>
                    </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.id_promotor')"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
       
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="https://< REST service IP:port>/promotor/1.0.0/prueba/id/9"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
```

Al ejecutar el servicio me mostro el siguiente error "no se puede encontrar una ruta de certificación válida para el objetivo solicitado". Investigando encontre que este problema se debia a que tenia que incluir el certificado de confianza del servicio externo, pero al volver ejecutar el servicio me mostro el mismo error:

```
[EI-Core] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:255)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

¿Podría alguno de ustedes ayudarme con esta problematica?